# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I get that error in my GetForumsByForumGroupID method where it selects the Forum object in my Linq statment. I haven't had this error before so i don't know what it is why I have it. I don't even need the Forum object i just need the Title and ForumID properties but I don't know how to return a anonymous object e.g.

```
var forums = (from x in db.Forums select new {ForumID = x.ForumID, Title = x.Title}).ToList();
```

Error in here. gets the selected forums passed on by dropdownlist

```
    public List<Forum> GetForumsByForumGroupID(int ForumGroupID)
    {
        using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities())
        {
            List<Forum> forums = (from x in db.Forums where x.ParentID == ForumGroupID select 
                              new Forum(x.ForumID, "",DateTime.Now, x.Title, "", 0, x.Importance, false, "",
                                  "", "", DateTime.Now, true, "", 0, "", DateTime.Now, "", 0, 0, "", 0)).ToList<Forum>();
            return forums;
        }
    }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"   AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Key" 
    DataValueField="Value">

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetDisplayForumGroups" TypeName="CMS.Framework.Forums">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ForumID" HeaderText="ForumID" 
            SortExpression="ForumID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AddedBy" HeaderText="AddedBy" 
            SortExpression="AddedBy" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AddedDate" HeaderText="AddedDate" 
            SortExpression="AddedDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
            SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentID" HeaderText="ParentID" 
            SortExpression="ParentID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Importance" HeaderText="Importance" 
            SortExpression="Importance" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Moderated" HeaderText="Moderated" 
            SortExpression="Moderated" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="Url" SortExpression="Url" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="ImageUrl" 
            SortExpression="ImageUrl" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedBy" HeaderText="UpdatedBy" 
            SortExpression="UpdatedBy" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedDate" HeaderText="UpdatedDate" 
            SortExpression="UpdatedDate" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" 
            SortExpression="Active" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ForumGroup" HeaderText="ForumGroup" 
            SortExpression="ForumGroup" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ThreadCount" HeaderText="ThreadCount" 
            SortExpression="ThreadCount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPostBy" HeaderText="LastPostBy" 
            SortExpression="LastPostBy" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPostDate" HeaderText="LastPostDate" 
            SortExpression="LastPostDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPostTitle" HeaderText="LastPostTitle" 
            SortExpression="LastPostTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPostID" HeaderText="LastPostID" 
            SortExpression="LastPostID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ThreadID" HeaderText="ThreadID" 
            SortExpression="ThreadID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ThreadTitle" HeaderText="ThreadTitle" 
            SortExpression="ThreadTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReplyCount" HeaderText="ReplyCount" 
            SortExpression="ReplyCount" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetForumsByForumGroupID" TypeName="CMS.Framework.Forums">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
        Type="Int32" Name="ForumGroupID" /> 
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Updated:

```
    public   GetForumsByForumGroupID(int ForumGroupID)
    {
        using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities())
        {
            var forums = (from x in db.Forums where x.ParentID == ForumGroupID select 
                              x).ToList();
            return forums;
        }
    }
```

Can't do this either

```
    public List<Forum>  GetForumsByForumGroupID(int ForumGroupID)
    {
        using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities())
        {
            List<Forum> formus = (from x in db.Forums where x.ParentID == ForumGroupID select 
                              x).ToList<Forum>();
            return forums;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `db.Forums` a collection of `Forum` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating new `Forum` objects in the first place? Unless there's a good reason not to, just do `select x`.

Comment: @KDM: A list of whatever type `db.Forums` contains.

Comment: I still don't get it what do I return. I've updated my code at the bottom can you help me out please

Comment: @KDM: I'd imagine `db.Forums` contains `Forum` objects. Return a list of those. I think this should be perfectly clear to anybody who knows the basics of C#.

Comment: For some reason my mind has gone blank on me. I don't understand returning var forums, that type is turned into a ToList() i don't know what to return that as. I can't make that List<Forum>

Comment: @KDM: Have you for a separate Forum class, apart from the type contained in `db.Forums`? Also, `var` is not magical. Unless you're dealing with anonymous types, you can always replace it with a type name.

Comment: Yeah I have a Forum Class with some properties that are nullable that don't exist in the db.Forums table.

Comment: @KDM: I'd rather add those properties to the DB class so you don't have two classes for the same thing (there's no need to have DB fields for them, of course, just add them in code). If you want to have two classes for the same thing, put an `AsEnumerable()` call inbetween to do the conversion outside Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: I don't get all this i just want to return var to the type can you update my code to reflect that.

Comment: I got it. it was System.Collections.Generic.IList<CMSModel.Forums>. I have another question? in this part of the Designer edmx     public partial class Forums : EntityObject
 can I add new Forum(int ForumID, ... etc) constructor and add other Properties that aren't in the DataBase

Comment: @KDM: Probably not, I avoid the designer because less generated code is better. The designer does produce partial classes though, so you can extend them outside the generated blob.